# ReadTimeout error when starting server sidekiq on ubuntu 14.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redis, sidekiq

I installed redis server by default it's running 6379 port but when i am running sidekiq its not starting, I added in Gemfile gem 'sidekiq', '3.3.0'

please help me out with this problem 
thanks in ADVANCE

this is the error

```
santosh@santosh-Vostro-3560:~/Roorah$ bundle exec sidekiq
Starting up a new ElasticSearch client with 
Net::ReadTimeout
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:158:in `rescue in rbuf_fill'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:152:in `rbuf_fill'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:134:in `readuntil'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:144:in `readline'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:39:in `read_status_line'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:28:in `read_new'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1408:in `block in transport_request'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1405:in `catch'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1405:in `transport_request'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1378:in `request'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.5.251/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/net.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in   request_with_newrelic_trace'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.5.251/lib/new_relic/agent.rb:454:in `disable_all_tracing'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.5.251/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/net.rb:26:in `block in request_with_newrelic_trace'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.5.251/lib/new_relic/agent/cross_app_tracing.rb:38:in `tl_trace_http_request'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.5.251/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/net.rb:23:in `request_with_newrelic_trace'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1371:in `block in request'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:853:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1369:in `request'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.5.251/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/net.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in request_with_newrelic_trace'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.5.251/lib/new_relic/agent.rb:454:in `disable_all_tracing'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.5.251/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/net.rb:26:in `block in request_with_newrelic_trace'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.5.251/lib/new_relic/agent/cross_app_tracing.rb:43:in `tl_trace_http_request'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.5.251/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/net.rb:23:in `request_with_newrelic_trace'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:80:in `perform_request'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:39:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:139:in `build_response'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:377:in `run_request'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.5/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:21:in `block in perform_request'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.5/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:187:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.5/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:187:in `perform_request'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.5/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:20:in `perform_request'
 /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.5/lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:104:in `perform_request'
 /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-api-1.0.5/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/bulk.rb:81:in `bulk'
 /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-model-0.1.6/lib/elasticsearch/model/importing.rb:120:in `block in import'
 /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-model-0.1.6/lib/elasticsearch/model/adapters/active_record.rb:96:in `block in __find_in_batches'
 /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:125:in `find_in_batches'
 /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/querying.rb:9:in `find_in_batches'
 /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-model-0.1.6/lib/elasticsearch/model/proxy.rb:80:in `method_missing'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-model-0.1.6/lib/elasticsearch/model/adapters/active_record.rb:95:in `__find_in_batches'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-model-0.1.6/lib/elasticsearch/model/importing.rb:119:in `import'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-model-0.1.6/lib/elasticsearch/model.rb:112:in `import'
 /home/santosh/Roorah/app/models/city_coordinate.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
   /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `block in load_file'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:633:in `new_constants_in'
 /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:442:in `load_file'
    /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `require_or_load'
    /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:307:in `depend_on'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:468:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
   /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `each'
   /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `block in eager_load!'
   /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `each'
    /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `eager_load!'
    /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
    /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `each'
    /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
     /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
     /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
 /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
   /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
      /home/santosh/Roorah/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support      /dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
         /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.3.0/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:236:in `boot_system'
        /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.3.0/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:50:in `run'
        /var/lib/ gems/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.3.0/bin/sidekiq:8:in `<top (required)>'
     /usr/local/bin/sidekiq:23:in `load'
```

Here is the `city_coordinate` model

```
class CityCoordinate < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
  # Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new url: ENV['BONSAI_URL'], log: true

end

CityCoordinate.import
```

Comment: Did u install elasticsearch & is it running?

Comment: @hkumar yes i installed elasticsearch also and running successfully

Comment: Please post `/home/santosh/Roorah/app/models/city_coordinate.rb:8:`